# Via dynamic user interaction can a node be created and/or linked in cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is it possible to implement the following usability concept in cytoscape.js?

1. Users can add new nodes to the grid by left-clicking on an empty spot.
2. Users can connect two nodes A and B by pressing the left mouse button over A and releasing the left button mouse button over B. (While users are holding the left mouse button a "preview edge" appears between A and the current mouse position.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), you could use `cy.on('tap', ...)` and determine the grid row/col based on the model co-ordinates of the event.

As of 2016-08-19, there are two existing extensions for helping with grid alignment UI:

- [`cytoscape-grid-guide`](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-grid-guide)
- [`cytoscape-snap-to-grid`](https://github.com/guimeira/cytoscape-snap-to-grid)

Generally, extensions have a `demo.html` so you can explore their features. There is a [list in the docs](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions), and new ones are being added all the time (both first party and third party).

You may also be interested in the [`grid`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/grid) layout.

For (2), there are extensions that do exactly what you mention, each with different extra features and options:

- [`cytoscape-edgehandles`](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-edgehandles)
- [`cytoscape-edge-ediation`](https://github.com/frankiex/cytoscape.js-edge-editation)